# belongs_to and has_many association problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models **User**  and Hobbie model. Hobbie has already 4 records like music, sports, books and other.

Then I have form where I can create User and there  I can select from checkboxes those Hobbies at least 2.

**User.rb**

```
has_many: hobbies
```

**Hobbie.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
```

**Form:**

```
 <%= form_for(@user,  :remote=>"true",:html => {:id=>"new_user","data-parsley-validate" => true,:multipart => true}, remote: true ,format: :json) do |f| %>
               ...

         <% @hobbies.each do |hobbie| %>
              <li>

                <%= check_box_tag 'hobbie_ids[]',hobbie.id%> <%= h hobbie.name %>                       
              </li>        
                 <%= f.submit %>
         <% end %>
     <% end %>
```

When I create user with hobbies like music and sports it saves without problems.

```
t= User.last
t.hobbies => "music", "sports"
```

**Problem**: When I go for second user and select hobbies like sports and books and save.

Then in console:

```
t.User.last
t.hobbies => "sports" and "books"
```

But for first User there is just "music" left.

I can't figure it out. Do I need to use other assocciation type to get this to work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A standard `has_many` : `belongs_to` relationship in rails will only allow a single `user` per `hobby`.

This is due to the fact that the relationship is defined by a single integer column (`user_id`) on the `hobby` table. The following image from the Rails Guides illustrates this relationship:

[image: has_many relationship illustration]

What you most likely are looking for is a [`has_and_belongs_to_many` relationsship](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association):

[image: Image from Rails Guides]

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :hobbies
end

class Hobby < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class CreateUsersAndHobbies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    create_table :hobbies do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    create_table :users_hobbies, id: false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user, index: true
      t.belongs_to :hobby, index: true
    end
  end
end
```

The key difference here being that the relationship between hobby and user is stored in the `users_hobbies` join table.